# Besides "flood plain", is there also something similar called "flood plane"?

Tags: synonyms, terminology

Having stumbled upon the term *flood plane* (meaning the area along a river that is flooded occasionally), I searched for it and the correct spelling seems to be *flood plain*. Now, some uncertainty remains with me. It is caused by one answer ([source](http://www.answers.com/Q/Which_is_correct_spelling-flood_plain_or_flood_plane)) that holds *flood plane* is geographically correct but in normal use its *flood plain*.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flood%20plain%2C%20flood%20plane&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cflood%20plain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cflood%20plane%3B%2Cc0) suggests that *flood plain* is the normal spelling, while *flood plane* is very rare. It was a little more common in the early 20th century, but still a fraction of the frequency of *flood plain*.

A *plain* is a flat area of land, while a *plane* is a flat geometric object. Since *flood plain* refers to land areas, it makes more sense for it to be the correct phrase.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation and for referring me to the Ngrams graph. That makes it quite obvious.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>*Flood plane* is a spelling error.  The fact that the error is "find-able" via web searches does not make it any less an error.  This is similar to "seperate" - also a spelling error even though it is a common error.</strike>

**EDIT**

As EdwinAshworth has discovered, the term *flood plane* exists.  It is not an alternate spelling of *flood plain.*

1. *Flood plain* refers to a geograpic area that is susceptible to flooding.
2. *Flood plane* refers to the position of the surface of water during a flood.

Comment: It's common to find spelling errors on the web, but not so common to find a web page that actually claims that the error is correct.

Comment: @Barmar My access to OED online expired some time ago.......perhaps another poster can help us.

Comment: Your access to the [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of Scientific & Technical Terms](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/flood+plane) is almost certainly the same as mine: '**flood plane** [′fləd ‚plān]
(hydrology)
The position of a stream's water surface during a particular flood.'

Comment: I would guess that most literate hydrologists avoid using "flood plane" in it's "correct" sense, due to the likely confusion.  There are other terms -- "flood depth", et al -- that describe the height of the flood without being so confusing.

Answer (score 0):

A *[plane](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/plane#plane)* would be a mathematically defined flat surface:

> noun
>
> 1.0 A flat surface on which a straight line joining any two points on it would wholly lie:

A *[plain](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/plain)* is an area of ground and generally not "flat" in the mathematical sense:

> noun
>
> A large area of flat land with few trees:

Even if it were and area of land of constant elevation, it would follow the curvature of the earth and not be a plane.  FEMA (the "Federal Emergency Mapping Agency) creates floodplain maps to define where flooding is more likely to happen.  They spell "floodplain" as one word, but I think most dictionaries state that it is properly spelled as one word or two.

Comment: One of the definitions of [plane](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/plane) is: A flat or level surface of a material object:
*the **plane** of his forehead*. This definition tends to contradict your thesis--even though it is technically correct.